# Can I access url kwargs in django template context processor?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

```
urls.py

url(r'^(?i)(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$', views_search.index, name='articles'),
```

context_processor.py

```
def get_username(request, **kwargs):
    print kwargs
    slug = kwargs.get('slug')
    return {
    'slug': slug
    }
```

But when i am running it, its printing empty dict and nothing is returned to the template. I have added this in template context processors in setting. How can I access kwargs here ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The url kwargs are specific to the view. So why not just add them to the context there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If an url is resolved, the [`ResolverMatch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.ResolverMatch) object is set as an attribute on the request:

```
def get_username(request):
    if hasattr(request, 'resolver_match'):
        slug = request.resolver_match.kwargs.get('slug')
        return {'slug': slug}
    return {}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, for class based views, the `view` is already available in the context, so you can directly access `kwargs` in the template. In the template, just do the following:

```
{{ view.kwargs.slug }}
```

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45099100/1526703) SO answer